# Checking if a table exists using context.TableName is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I'm working on a web application as a team with my classmates. We're using a code first approach, as we use migrations and models.

Now, in one of my Services, I feel the need to check if a table in a database exists.

```
public class TransactionService : ITransactionService
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly DataContext _context;

    public TransactionService(IMapper mapper, DataContext context)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
        _context = context;
        
    }

    public async Task<TransactionResponseDTO> GetAllTransactions(int pageNumber, int pageSize)
    {
       
        if (pageNumber < 0) throw new ArgumentException("Page number cannot be negative");
        if (pageSize < 0) throw new ArgumentException("Page size cannot be negative");

        if (!_context.Database.CanConnect())
        {
            throw new Exception("Unable to connect to database.");
        }

        if(_context.Transactions is null) 
        {
            throw new Exception("No table matches the name 'Transactions'.");
        }
          return response; 
       }
```

With the

```
 if (!_context.Database.CanConnect())
        {
            throw new Exception("Unable to connect to database.");
        }
```

I check if the database can be connected to, and with

```
if(_context.Transactions is null) 
    {
        throw new Exception("No table matches the name 'Transactions'.");
    }
```

I intend to check if the table Transactions exists in the database. Now, when I delete the table Transactions from the database and when I run my application using dotnet watch run and if I then search for a transaction or a page of transactions, I get the error

> Error: Invalid object name 'Transactions'.

This is caught by my try-catch block in TransactionController, but which **is not** the message I intended it to be (which is No table matches the name 'Transactions'.). This prompts me to think that there is another if clause I should use to check for the existence of the table. Can anyone help out? Thanks!

Comment: This seems a bit odd. How would the table disappear from the database?

Comment: @stuartd I have no idea. I am working in a team of eight classmates and most of them recommended we add a way to check if a table exists in a database. I figured we'd just do that until we have our weekly meeting with our teaching staff where they'll probably say it's redundant.

Comment: Generally if a table disappears things will immediately stop working!

Comment: You’d be better off spending your time on the project functionality rather than this. If you really want to, just catch the ‘Invalid object name’ exception but honestly I wouldn’t even bother with that.

Comment: Are you connecting to the right database and schema when you run the application? check your connection strings.